# How to use foreach when there is no array in the object?

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach

I was using this successfully, so I thought:

```
foreach ($trip->STOPS->STOP as $key=>$value) {
```

Most of the time the data looks like this:

```
  ["STOPS"]=>
  object(stdClass)#247 (1) {
    ["STOP"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#248 (2) {
        ["NAME"]=>
        string(11) "Short Hills"
        ["TIME"]=>
        string(20) "7/30/2013 6:38:24 AM"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#249 (2) {
        ["NAME"]=>
        string(8) "Millburn"
        ["TIME"]=>
        string(20) "7/30/2013 6:41:24 AM"
      }
      [2]=>
      object(stdClass)#250 (2) {
        ["NAME"]=>
        string(19) "Newark Broad Street"
        ["TIME"]=>
        string(20) "7/30/2013 6:53:00 AM"
      }
      [3]=>
      object(stdClass)#251 (2) {
        ["NAME"]=>
        string(21) "New York Penn Station"
        ["TIME"]=>
        string(20) "7/30/2013 7:13:00 AM"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However the above PHP code caused a problem when STOP didn't contain an array of elements, when it looked like this:

```
  ["STOPS"]=>
  object(stdClass)#286 (1) {
    ["STOP"]=>
    object(stdClass)#287 (2) {
      ["NAME"]=>
      string(21) "New York Penn Station"
      ["TIME"]=>
      string(20) "7/30/2013 8:13:00 AM"
    }
  }
}
```

So as you might guess, the instead of it making $key=>$value to be the array element and the array of the NAME/TIME, it was making $key to be NAME or TIME, which is wrong of course.

How can I use this foreach method properly without having to check to see if foreach $trip->STOPS->STOP contains an array or more than one element?

The source of this data is from a SOAP request which is returned as JSON.

Or is my approach here totally wrong? If so, please kindly enlighten me? Thanks!

Comment: The clue is in the manual. _foreach works only on arrays and objects_ if you do not have an array or an object to iterate over then do not use foreach

Comment: Are you getting results from a database? ... The reason that I ask is that you could apply a bit of a dirty hack whereby you manipulate the query.

Comment: Have you even tried your code? because it _should_ work just fine. All objects can be iterated over using a foreach loop, even custom objects (albeit you'll only see the `public` properties). Besides, if you're more comfortable with an array: `$arr = (array) $someObject;` is possible (casting objects to array)

Comment: @Anigel Thanks for the reply. But it doesn't send back output the same each time from this SOAP request I'm doing, so I won't know if it is arrays or just a pointer to a single object (lack a better term for this).

Comment: You can still use if (is_array()) to find out if that is an array and use foreach or do something different if it is not.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Yes, the code blows up because it is returning NAME or TIME for $key when there is an object like the second one.

Comment: @Anigel That sounds workable, but is the method for dealing with this Object of mine flawed to begin with which might be creating this problem? Or is this a normal solution to this sort of problem?

Comment: @Edvard it was making $key to be NAME or TIME, which is wrong of course <<< This is not wrong, is the correct way for foreach to behave. If you have array it iterates over elements like $key => $value. If you give object to foreach it will iterate trough public properties like $key='property name => $value='Property value'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value of the `STOP` property is *either* an array, containg several `stdClass` instances, or a single instance of `stdClass`, you can simply check that, and reassign the property:

```
if ($trip->STOPS->STOP instanceof stdClass)
{
    $trip->STOPS->STOP = array($trip->STOPS->STOP);
}
foreach($trip->STOPS->STOP as $key => $object)
{
    echo $key, implode(',', (array) $object);
}
```

What I've done is simply *check*: is STOP an array, then I change nothing, is it an instance of `stdClass`, I create a wrapper-array, that contains that very object, so the value of `$key` will always be what it needs to be.

However, since you're looping over those objects, to treat them one by one (I guess), it would be far better to create a function:

```
function todoWhatYouDoInLoop(stdClass $object)
{
    //do stuff
    //in case the objects are altered:
    return $object;
}
```

Which you can use like so:

```
if (is_array($trip->STOPS->STOP))
{
    $trip->STOPS->STOP = array_map('todoWhatYouDoInLoop', $trip->STOPS->STOP);
}
else
{
    $trip->STOPS->STOP = todoWhatYouDoInLoop($trip->STOPS->STOP);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're dealing with different type of structures. You should ensure that `$trip->STOPS->STOP` is an array or else make it an array. Like so:

```
if (is_array($trip->STOPS->STOP)) {
    $stopArray = $trip->STOPS->STOP;
} else {
    // wrap it in array with single element
    $stopArray = array( $trip->STOPS->STOP );
}
foreach ($stopArray as $key=>$value) {
    // your code...
```